# Windows Virtual Desktop

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Is there a way to set a projection mode per virtual desktop?

Example

- Virtual desktop 1: Extend
- Virtual desktop 2: Mirrow

For example: Presentation (desktop 1) in extend mode and code examples (desktop 2) mirrored.

Comment: I'm afraid not out of the box, I remember I had use a third party application to create virtual desktop on windows, may that application can handle different configuration per virtual desktop